# Uploaded pdfs are blurry on LinkedIn profile page

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf

On my LinkedIn profile page (under the Summary), uploaded pdfs look blurry. Individually, when selected, the quality is fine. Files are created in InDesign CS5 using Adobe preset "High Quality Print", following recommendation by Adobe. LinkedIn tech support says the issue is that the pdfs are not of high quality but is not specific on what individual settings should be when creating pdfs. Posts on LinkedIn help section note that others have had the same problem, but there are no corresponding answers. Can anyone help? Thank you.

Comment: Are these PDFs blurry anywhere else?

Comment: No, they're fine in Acrobat and also when they're viewed individually on LinkedIn.

Comment: It sounds like they only look bad in the thumbnail - I don't think PDFs include a thumbnail in themselves, I think that is generated by the OS or website. I tested some PDF uploads to my own profile though, and they looked reasonable. My guess is still that it is LinkedIn though. Sorry I can't be of more help!

Comment: Thank you for going to the trouble of testing this issue. Can I ask what preset and compression settings you used? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3):

The solution to this issue of poor quality pdf work samples on my LinkedIn profile page, was to set up a Behance portfolio with the same images and then (from the LinkedIn profile page) import the Behance project links. Working in this way, the quality of the images is fine.

Comment: I noticed the same thing on my LinkedIn profile.